# SQL query is correct but still a "SQL error 1064" appears

Tags: mysql, cakephp, mysql-error-1064

I can't deal with it. I'm experiencing big troubles with this very query:

```
UPDATE books 
SET books.out = books.out + 1 
WHERE id = 81813130; 

UPDATE books 
SET books.available = 0 
WHERE books.in = books.out;
```

If I run it on my phpMyAdmin, everything's fine and everything completes, but in my CakePHP application this query doesn't work and when I perform a debug this is what I'm told:

> Warning (512): SQL Error: 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE books SET books.available = 0 WHERE books.in = books.out' at line 1**

I'm calling my query from a controller:

```
$this->Lending->update_lendings($this->data['Lending']['book_id']);
```

and the actual query is of course into the model:

```
$query = "
    UPDATE books 
    SET books.out = books.out + 1 
    WHERE id = ".$id."; 

    UPDATE books 
    SET books.available = 0 
    WHERE books.in = books.out;
          ";
```

I really can't say why this isn't working. It seems that `error 1064 Mysql` is a very common question in here but I didn't find anything useful about my very issue.

I steadfastly thank you for your support and help.

Comment: Perhaps you can't run 2 statements with one go? Have you tried sedning the two updates with 2 separate calls?

Comment: not really related to your question, but why do you store in the database information that is derivable from existing data ? isn't available =  in - out , all the time ?

Comment: @ypercube, I split the updates into two separates call and now it works. I'm baffled: why did it perfectly work into phpMyAdmin?

Comment: Because they are different envirorments (PHPMyAdmin and the library you use to connect from Cake). You can run multiple queries and statements in PHPMyAdmin. But several libraries do not support more than one query/statement per call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the second Update statement is meant to change only the row that the first statement updated, then you could use a single Update:

```
UPDATE books 
SET out = out + 1
  , available = CASE WHEN in = out
                       THEN 0
                       ELSE available
                END
WHERE id = 81813130
```

Comment: Oh my, this could be The Solution. I'm going to try this for sure!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your problem might be due to PHP's lack of support for Multiple Statement Execution. Multiple Statement Execution allows you to run two queries in a single request and receive multiple result-sets in response.

MySQL *DOES* support it, but the default setup in PHP prevents this (that is, if you're using the deprecated `mysql_connect()` era functions). This is actually a nice default because there are some serious bugs that can be introduced by allowing multiple-queries (see SQL injection).

So, the solution could be to alter your code to request the data separately.

```
$query = "
UPDATE books 
SET books.out = books.out + 1 
WHERE id = ".$id.";";

mysql_query($db, $query);

$query = "UPDATE books 
SET books.available = 0 
WHERE books.in = books.out;";

mysql_query($db, $query);
```

That being said, if you think that it's safe enough to use multi-statements (that is, if all of the input values are sanitized), then go ahead and try to use the `mysqli` functions (there not even deprecated!).

`mysqli_multi_query( $query )` should give you the flexibility you need.

Comment: If switching to mysql_i_ solves it, maybe updating your `APP/config/database.php` file and setting your default connection to using mysqli will fix your problem then. Although I'm not sure that CakePHP will support returning multiple return sets...

Answer (score 1):

aparently, it's because you use reserved words in your query, try and escape all table names and table columns in ``` `` ```

list of reserved words in mysql [available here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html)

Comment: thank you for your comment. I didn't really use "in" and "out" for my query, but since my variables aren't written in english I translated them to make you better unserstand the scenario.